# How to replace a double for with a stream (with incrementing)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I write a java code like this with the stream api?

```
int i = 0;
for (Foo[] foo : foo.getFoo()) {
    for (Bar bar : foo) {
        if (bar.getSometing() == something) {
            return "something"
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know, maybe you should keep the current code (to ease maintenance). Are you sure about your `==` And how is `i` usefull in this code?

Comment: Not all streams will short circuit the way your current code will, so it may not be more efficient to replace with a stream.

Comment: It's not clear what this code is meant to do. Are you checking whether an array contains any element that meets a certain criteria?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm looking for. Does a better, faster solution exists?

Comment: What's the return type of `foo.getFoo()`?

Comment: `for (Bar bar : foo)` doesn't make sense unless `Foo` is a subtype of `Bar`.

Comment: You still didn’t explain the relevance of the `i` variable. In case of a match, it will be ignored, as `"something"` is immediately returned (if you add the missing semicolon), in case of no match, you executed whatever code is after the loop, but in this case, `i` will invariably contain `foo.getFoo().length`…

Answer (score 0):

You want the `anyMatch` method, and `flatMap` for the nested arrays/collections:

```
Collection<Bar[]> foo2 = foo.getFoo();
if (foo2.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).anyMatch(bar -> bar.getSomething() == something)) {
    return "something";
}
```

This looks nicer, but runs slower than the for-each version since Java streams have a lot of overhead. You can try adding `.parallel()` before `flatMap`, but whether that helps depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```
return Arrays.stream(foo.getFoo())
    .flatMap(foo -> foo.getBar().stream())
    .filter(bar -> bar.getSomething().equals(something))
    .findAny()
    .map(a -> "something")
    .orElse("some default return value");
```

I have used my imagination on a few things for the code above:

- The `Foo` class has a `getBar()` method that returns a `List<Bar>`
- You want to use `equals(something)` instead of `== something` in the filter condition
- There exists some other return value for when a `Bar` instance is not found
- What's the use of the counter variable `i`? I haven't include it in my answer, because you aren't showing what you are doing with it